# JavaScript To Strip Page For URL

Tags: javascript, regex

We have a javascript function we use to track page stats internally. However, the URLs it reports many times include the page numbers for search results pages which we would rather not be reported. The pages that are reports are of the form:

```
http://www.test.com/directory1/2
http://www.test.com/directory1/subdirectory1/15
http://www.test.com/directory3/1113
```

Instead we'd like the above reported as:

```
http://www.test.com/directory1
http://www.test.com/directory1/subdirectory1
http://www.test.com/directory3
```

Please note that the numbered 'directory' and 'subdirectory' names above are just for example purposes and that the actual subdirectory names are all different, don't necessarily include numbers at the end of the directory name, and can be many levels deep.

Currently our JavaScript function produces these URLs using the code:

```
var page = location.hostname+document.location.pathname;
```

I believe we need to use the JavaScript replace function in combination with some regex but I'm at a complete loss as to what that would look like. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex for this:

```
document.location.pathname.replace(/\/\d+$/, "");
```

Unlike `substring` and `lastIndexOf` solutions, this will strip off the end of the path if it consists of digits only.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this:

`var page = location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf("/"));`

Answer (score 0):

I would think you need to use the .htaccess with rewrite rules to change the look of the url, however I am still looking to see if this is available to javascript. Will repost when I find out more

EDIT*

the lastIndexOf would only give you the position, therefor you would still need to replace. ex:

> var temp = page.substring(page.lastIndexOf("/"),page.length-1);
>
> page = page.replace(temp, "");

unfortunately I'm not that advanced in my coding so there is probably more efficient coding in the other answers. Sorry for any inconveniences with my initial answer.

Comment: @Justin - I don't want to actually change the page URLs for the site visitors. Instead I want to update our internal tracking JavaScript to strip off the page numbers of any URLs that contain them when it's being reported to our backend tracking script. The JavaScript calls the script and reports the page URL. It should be a relatively simple regex to do it but I'm not sure what that looks like. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Russell the lastIndexOf would only give you the position, therefor you would still need to replace. 
ex: var temp = page.substring(page.lastIndexOf("/"),page.length-1);
page = page.replace(temp, ""); 
unfortunately I'm not that advanced in my coding so there is probably more efficient coding in the other answers. Sorry for any inconveniences with my initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is find the last index of "/" and then use the substring function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need a regex if you're just pulling off the last slash + content.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastIndexOf.asp

I'd probably use that to search for the last "/" character, then do a substring from the start of the string to that index.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var page = location.split("/");
page.pop();
page = page.join("/");
```